# Sphins Regexp maps to only single words

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to map regexp so when a user enters a specific word I force them to choose a specific other term in the table.

For instance I have as simple example fields:

- Bob
- Bob Smith
- Bob Jones
- Sally
- Sally Smith
- Sally Jones

If I do

`regexp_filter=Bob>Bob Smith` to make sure when a user simply enters `Bob` I push `Bob Smith` instead and then do a `sphinql` search:

`Select * from Index where MATCH('Bob')`

I still get all the `Bob` records (in other words it did not interpret as `Bob Smith`

However if I dod

`regexp_filter=Bob=>Sally`

Then `Select * from Index where MATCH('Bob')` returns all the `Sally` records.

I am "simply" trying to force the index to return the `Bob Jones` record should a user simply search on `Bob`.

FYI I did try

`Select * from Index where MATCH('^Bob$')`

and that returned NULL

Answer (score 0):

> I still get all the Bob records (in other words it did not interpret as Bob Smith

Because the regex is applied to BOTH the query text **and** document text during indexing. So becomes `MATCH('Bob Smith')`, but your documents also become

- `Bob Smith`
- `Bob Smith Smith`
- `Bob Smith Jones`

... so your query, matches all three documents, same if didnt have the regex!

---

> I am "simply" trying to force the index to return the Bob Jones record should a user simply search on Bob.

Wonder if you meaning should NOT return ?

... in which case can use `MATCH('^Bob$')` but rememeber to remove the regex. Or could perhaps use  `MATCH('"^Bob$"')` an extra set of quotes to use phrase mode.

Try also `MATCH('^Bob$ ')` with a space! some versions of sphinx has a bug unless a space after the `$`!

Comment: True but in fact my regexp ended up as `regexp_filter=^Bob$>Bob Smith` which should only turn Bob into Bob Smith

Comment: Well I would think that WOULDNT match a query `MATCH('^Bob$')` - but the document HAS been changed to `Bob Smith` - so NO matches.

Comment: Hmm ok well my desired result is that whenever a user searches on `Bob` (aka `^Bob$`) it returns `Bob Smith`

Comment: In other words a search on `Bob Smith` returns `Bob Smith`, a search on `Bob Jones` returns `Bob Jones` but a search on `Bob` returns only `Bob Smith`

Comment: @BarrytHunter I wonder if doing a regex so `Bob > Bob Smith` and `Bob Smith Smith > Bob Smith` would work? Now `Bob` is stored as `Bob Smith`, `Bob Smith` is first converted to `Bob Smith Smith` and then `Bob Smith` and finally a search on `^Bob$` should in theory search for `^Bob Smith$`?

Comment: Sorry misspelled the @ name last post so it missed you, here it is again: I wonder if doing a regex so Bob > Bob Smith and Bob Smith Smith > Bob Smith would work? Now Bob is stored as Bob Smith, Bob Smith is first converted to Bob Smith Smith and then Bob Smith and finally a search on ^Bob$ should in theory search for ^Bob Smith$?

Comment: have to be honest not sure what you really trying to do. But test it?